# How to perform normal mathemathical tasks with microcontroller + pentium 4 processor

Tags: arduino, x86

I just got an old pentium 4 and I thought, that it would be nice to calculate some heavy maths with it.
So I have a arduino duemilanove and I know, that how To send data in to the processor, but I dont know how I specify to processor that what mathematical things it should do (like multiplication, sqrt, sin and so on), and how do I specify that where do I get those answers out of the processor.

Comment: you can't drive pentium with arduino...

Comment: @Anycorn "can't" is a bit strong, perhaps crazy. ;)

Comment: @kenny You're right but just the thought of 16MHz micro acting as a controller for 3Ghz Intel ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make an application that you download into Arduino duemilanove and you make an application for your Pentium 4 computer. These applications need to exchange data via some communication channel like existing USB/FTDI/RS232. You need to learn how to send/receive data to/from it in both Arduino programming language and your favorite PC programming language. Then you need to make a protocol that both part will understand. Arduino will send a message that will include all inputs needed for computation, and PC will reply with a computation result. You will also need to learn how to download application to Arduino, and many other things on this way, but I strongly advice you to start with blinking leds. That's a hello world application for microcontrollers and every newbie should start with this little step first.

Comment: I already know, that how to blink leds with arduino, and I know arduino language / c really well

Comment: "Then you need to make a protocol that both part will understand." Arduino can generate a message like this: <PREFIX><MATH EXPRESSION><SUFIX><CRC>, and on PC side you need to run a math expression parser and evaluator that will reply with a computation result message interpreted and used by Arduino. Expression parsers can be made by your self or 3rd party.

Comment: What is that message op there?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that I gonna build a kernel to drive the basic functions of the processor, and I use agtl converted to ttl for arduino/cpu communication.

Comment: That sounds extremely ambitious.  Were you going to try to build an SMP-like system where the Arduino is like a 2nd CPU sharing memory with the P4, connected to the same frontside bus (on a multi-socket P4 server board?), or are you going to make the Arduino act like a Northbridge chipset for the P4 to talk to instead of a northbridge with a memory controller?  Both of these sound fairly insane vs. sending messages over a simpler but higher latency standard interface like USB, ethernet, parallel port, or even just simple serial.  Did this hobby project ever go anywhere?